# Access Meta Data from android WebView

Tags: android, webview, meta-tags

How to access Meta Data of a HTML page loaded into a WebView in Android?

I search for hours stackoverflow.com and google and I coudn't find any answer.

I only could get url and title by this code:

```
webView.getTitle();
webView.getUrl();
```

Dose is it imposible and webview not support it?

Comment: what kind of data exactly you want to get/view?

Comment: @Aman Grover  for example description meta tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't open the URL in the `WebView`.

First. open an `HttpURLConnection` to the URL.  Read the output from the server and you can scan through the server response to find your meta data.

As you are reading the server output, write the data into a buffer, then use `loadData` instead of `loadUrl` to display the buffered data in the `WebView`

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem by this easy way:

```
private class JsInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void processHTML(String content) {
    //handle content
    }
}


mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsInterface(), "CC_FUND");

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.CC_FUND.processHTML( (function (){var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'); \n" +
                "\n" +
                "   for (var i=0; i<metas.length; i++) { \n" +
                "      if (metas[i].getAttribute(\"name\") == \"description\") { \n" +
                "         return metas[i].getAttribute(\"content\"); \n" +
                "      } \n" +
                "   } \n" +
                "\n" +
                "    return \"\";})() );");
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If its your own web page then you can pass the meta description or any text to your app using the below code:

```
public class WebAppInterface {

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        mDescription = desc;
    }
}
```

Then add JS interface to WebView:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "Android");
```

Finally, add the following code in your webpage:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    Android.setDesc("Your meta tag desc here");
</script>
```

Read more at https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html